# User Controls and strongly typed data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, user-controls

I am trying to pass a strongly typed object to a UserControl, but I am not able. I must be missing something. So my User Control expects an object of type Data which contains a list of string. On my page, I call RenderPartial with the name of my user control and the data. However, when the page run, it says in that this.Model (or this.ViewData.Model) is null. Why? What am I missing?

**Page.aspx**

```
<% Html.RenderPartial("UserControl", ViewData["Data"]); %>
```

**PageController.cs**

```
ViewData["Data"] = new Data() 
{ 
    Links = new List<Link> 
    { 
    } 
};
```

**Data.cs**

```
public class Data
{
    public List<string> Links { get; set; }
}
```

**UserControl.ascx**

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<Proto.Models.Data>" %> 
    <% 
        foreach (var link in this.Model.Links)
        { 
           // ...
        }
    %>
```

Comment: Can you show the action method?

Answer (score 1):

`ViewData` just contains a mapping of `string` -> `object`. You need to cast it to the type that your strong-typed view is expecting:

```
<% Html.RenderPartial("UserControl", (Data) ViewData["Data"]); %>
```

Personally, I would suggest that you make *everything* strong-typed, and eschew the use of `ViewData` entirely, but I understand that's not always possible :)